# Ansible only notify when run single roles

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I don't know why my ansible configuration only notify when i run single roles.

If i use this config

```
---
- name: Install PHP-Fpm, Nginx, MariaDB, pure-ftpd on CentOS 7 with Optimized
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - nginx
```

Ansible return
`https://pastebin.com/pW7Npj60`

But if i use this configuration

```
---
- name: Install PHP-Fpm, Nginx, MariaDB, pure-ftpd on CentOS 7 with Optimized
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - nginx
    - mariadb
```

Ansible return `https://pastebin.com/tvkdpJiD`

It's that mean ansible skip starting service ?

Comment: please post your mariadb task (code).

Comment: thanks Berlin. Here my code https://pastebin.com/hG8WDvNi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mariadb` role has failed tasks, so host is marked as failed and no handler for this failed host is executed.

By default all handlers from every role are executed after all roles are applied and if host is not failed.

You can either:

- Use [force_handlers](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#force-handlers) option to force Ansible to execute handlers even if there is failed task for this host.
- Use [meta: flush_handlers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/meta_module.html) as the last task of your roles to forcefully execute handlers (if they were triggered) after every role.

Comment: Here my mariadb task https://pastebin.com/hG8WDvNi. I'm make sure it's correct. Mariadb failed due can not start (notify)

Comment: Please read my answer – handlers are executed **after all roles are applied**. If you need to execute handlers in the middle of the role, use `flush_handers`.